# assetic filter and entity manager

Tags: symfony, assetic

i've been search a dey for an answer but i don't find it.

How can I Use assetic to load data from the database?

with this filter

```
<?php

namespace project\bundle\mybundle\Assetic;

use Assetic\Asset\AssetInterface;
use Assetic\Filter\FilterInterface;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class CssFilter implements FilterInterface
{
protected $entityManager;
protected $container;

public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, Container $container)
{
    $this->entityManager   = $entityManager;
    $this->container       = $container;
}

public function filterLoad(AssetInterface $asset)
{

}


public function filterDump(AssetInterface $asset)
{
     $content   = $asset->getContent();

    $themeId   = 3;
    $theme     = $this->entityManager->getRepository('projectBundle:Theme')->find($themeId);
    $css       = $theme->getCss();

    $asset->setContent($css);

}
```

}

i'm able to load the css from database but only on time, each time i reload my css it use the precompile version.

How can i for assetic to use the dump or load fonction on each page load?

i've been searching i can't find any answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `style` tags instead of include file

```
<style>
    /* import styles from db */
</style>
```

and use page cache.

Comment: In fact i was searching for a solution to user assetic filter and entitymanager to dynamicly load Data from database, would have been great if it was possible.
I red the code from the saas filter of assetic and visibly he does nearly the same and finnaly he do a assetic:dump... For me it's not a solution. I will not be able to use assetic form my probleme i think

but ty for your help